# Why does my code return 4390 instead of 5062 for Oxford dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataset

I wrote a code to read [Oxford building dataset](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/oxbuildings/). Based on the official website, the dataset contains 5062 images and groundtruth to say which one belongs to [good,bad,ok,junk]. There is no "bad" in the groundtruth. There are about 100 query files. Therefore, there should be around 4900 images.

My code is as follows:

```
files = os.listdir('images')
files=sorted(files)
gt      = [os.path.join('groundtruth', a) for a in os.listdir('groundtruth')]
gt_good = list(set([a for a in gt if 'good' in a]))
gt_ok   = list(set([a for a in gt if 'ok' in a]))
gt_junk = list(set([a for a in gt if 'junk' in a]))
gt_query= list(set([a for a in gt if 'query' in a]))

z=0
cnt=0
allnames=[]
for text_file in gt_good:
  with open(text_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    names=(list(map(lambda a:a.strip(), f.readlines())))
  for name in names:
    allnames.append(name+".jpg")
    z=z+1

for text_file in gt_ok:
  with open(text_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    names = list(map(lambda a:a.strip(), f.readlines()))
  for name in names:
    allnames.append(name+".jpg")
    z=z+1

for text_file in gt_junk:
  with open(text_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    names = list(map(lambda a:a.strip(), f.readlines()))
  for name in names:
    allnames.append(name+".jpg")
    z=z+1

for text_file in gt_query:
  with open(text_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    names=(list(map(lambda a:a.strip(), f.readlines())))
  for name in names:
    allnames.append(name+".jpg")
    z=z+1
```

`z` is a counter to get how many items have been processed.
But the number of items is calculated 4390 instead of 5062. Why?
Did the creators change/remove files from "groundtruth" (very unlikely) or I am doing a silly mistake in my code?

Comment: Where is the number 4390 coming from in your code?

Comment: @mkrieger1, The "z" is 4390 after going through all groundtruth files and read the file names and add ".jpg"

Comment: What is the output of `print(len(files))` and `print(len(gt))` when adding these lines at the beginning?

Comment: @mkrieger1, the print(len(files)) gives you 5062. the len(gt)) gives you 220 as there are 220 text files. each of these files contains a list of image files. for example, file "all_souls_0001" contains names of 18 files which are categorized as "good". if you put everything together, then the len of gt is around 4900.

Answer (score 0):

After a while and be somehow an expert, I found what the reason is. I posted as an answer to help other people who came across this problem with old version of the dataset.
The reason is the corrupted images that PIL or OpenCV cannot read and simply ignore.
You should write an error handler helper or even use try+catch to handle this.

**NOTE:**
Oxford University has updated the dataset (April 2022) and the problem would not be there anymore as they blurred faces because of privacy. To do so, they hopefully fixed the dataset and those corrupted images!